# Shopify check for for tag [liquid]

Tags: shopify, liquid

```
{% for tag in product %}   
  {% if product.tags contains new %}
    <span>Test</span>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I need to look in products, and if a product has a tag called `new` then display a span tag if not then nothing.

For some reason, this piece of code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This can do the job :

```
{% for product in products %}   
  {% if product.tags contains "new" %}
    <span>Test</span>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```